# How can I create global variables in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, arrays, global-variables, xcode4.5

I'm a beginner in Xcode, but I've programmed in other languages, such as C++. I'm trying to have a global variable in my ViewContoller.m file that I can use in all of the functions. I want to make a globalized mutable array that stores strings. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean an instance variable? Instance variables can be used from all methods of a class. Global variables are usually shared through all of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use throughout the application, in all the classes then use Shared Instance/Singleton Class, to form a global variable.

If you want to access within a class create a property. This will be accessible throughout your class by `_propertyName` and `self.propertyName`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use properties for the classes, and NSNotificationCenter for that.